# Copy properties of objects inside ConfigurationElementCollection to an array?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-configuration

I created a custom configuration section and can add as many XML lines to my custom section and loop through and print them all. That works fine.

```
<eTMSoftware>
    <Program Id="1" Customer="SomeCust" Type="DC" InstalledLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\eMenuDesktopComponent 1.1.1.1_Customer" LogBaseDestination="C:\_eTM Logging"/>
    <Program Id="2" Customer="ThisCustNew" Type="DC" InstalledLocation="Some_Path" LogBaseDestination="DEST"/>
    <Program Id="3" Customer="AnotherNewCust" Type="DC" InstalledLocation="Some_Another_Path" LogBaseDestination="DEST"/>
</eTMSoftware>
```

I followed a guide on configuring custom configuration and I created a `ConfigurationElementCollection` for my `ConfigurationSection`.

My end goal: loop through the `ConfigurationElementCollection` (which contains the 3 XML nodes above) and add all of the `Customer` attributes to a string array.

I cannot figure out how to do this, because even though `ConfigurationElementCollection` derives from `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, I don't have access to the `Select()` or `Where()` methods.

Can anyone offer a solution?

I can supply code if needed. I thought It would be too much to put here at first.

Edit: here are 2 different ways I tried casting

```
public void VerifyShareDestinationsPerCustomer(eTMProgamsElementCollection configuredItems)
{
     string[] customersFromConfig = configuredItems.Cast<eTMProgramElement>()
                                                   .Select(p => p.Customer);
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (Are you missing a cast?).

```
public void VerifyShareDestinationsPerCustomer(eTMProgamsElementCollection configuredItems)
{
     string[] customersFromConfig = configuredItems.Cast<object>()
                                                   .Select(p => p.Customer);
}
```

Error:

> Object does not contain a definition for 'Customer' and no accessible extension method 'Customer' accepting a first argument of type 'Object' could be found.

**ANSWER FOUND:** I was able to add `ToArray<string>()` method to the end of the array definition and it worked with code from Haukinger! Thanks!

```
string[] customersFromConfig = configuredItems.Cast<eTMProgramElement>()
                                              .Select(p => p.Customer)
                                              .ToArray<string>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `IEnumerable<object>` then `Select` what you need

You can either cast directly (`(IEnumerable<object>)`) or use linq's `Cast<object>()`. Most of linq works on `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Cast my ConfigurationElementCollection? Thanks I will try this. I looked at the definition of ConfigurationElementCollection and it already derive from ICollection and IEnumerable so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Directly casting the collection object gives no access to Select(). Using Cast<>() gets me a little closer, but there are conversion error. I will update the question with 2 different techniques and the error text.

Comment: Adding .ToArray<string>() this the Cast<>() method worked! Thanks man you are genius.